# how to spawn a prefab with filled object fields from scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Public fields from the players scripts that are supposed to be filled with game objects from the scene aren't filled.

An example from one of the scripts: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smo9L.png)

What it should look like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A36Z4.png)

The code i'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

public MovementJoystick movementJoystick;
public int playerSpeed;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
bool facingRight = true;
public Animator animator;
public float interval;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    playerSpeed = 7;
    interval = 10;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.y != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movementJoystick.joystickVec.x * playerSpeed, movementJoystick.joystickVec.y * playerSpeed);
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(movementJoystick.joystickVec.x));
    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(0));
    }

    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.x < 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.x > 0 && facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (playerSpeed == 14 && interval > 0)
    {
        interval -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    else
    {
        playerSpeed = 7;
        interval = 10;
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);

    facingRight = !facingRight;
}

public void SpeedControl(int newplayerSpeed)
{
    playerSpeed = newplayerSpeed;
}
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MovementJoystick : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject joystick;
public GameObject joystickBG;
public Vector2 joystickVec;
private Vector2 joystickTouchPos;
private Vector2 joystickOriginalPos;
private float joystickRadius;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    joystickOriginalPos = joystickBG.transform.position;
    joystickRadius = joystickBG.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y / 2;
}

public void PointerDown()
{
    joystick.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    joystickBG.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    joystickTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
}

public void Drag(BaseEventData baseEventData)
{
    PointerEventData pointerEventData = baseEventData as PointerEventData;
    Vector2 dragPos = pointerEventData.position;
    joystickVec = (dragPos - joystickTouchPos).normalized;

    float joystickDist = Vector2.Distance(dragPos, joystickTouchPos);

    if (joystickDist < joystickRadius)
    {
        joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickDist;
    }

    else
    {
        joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickRadius;
    }
}

public void PointerUp()
{
    joystickVec = Vector2.zero;
    joystick.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
    joystickBG.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
}
}
```

How I am instantiating the player using Photon servers (the service I am using for multiplayer)

```
    public GameObject playerToSpawn;
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerToSpawn.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

There are also 2 buttons that don't work: a Shoot button and a Hit button. The code for them:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

The shooting script attached to the player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Button ShootButton;

void Start()
{
    ShootButton.onClick.AddListener(ShootButtonTrue);
}

void ShootButtonTrue()
{
    Shoot();
}

void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, 
firePoint.rotation);
}
}
```

The hitting script attached to the Hit button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HitButton : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

The Player Combat script using for hitting:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
public Animator animator;
public Button AttackButton;
public Transform attackPoint;
public float attackRange = 0.5f;
public LayerMask enemyLayers;

void Start()
{
    AttackButton.onClick.AddListener(AttackButtonTrue);
}

void AttackButtonTrue()
{
    Attack();
}

void Attack()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);
    foreach(Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        Debug.Log("u hit someone :O");
        enemy.GetComponent<Health>().TakeDamage(15);
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    if (attackPoint == null)
        return;

    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange);
}

}
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question over and over.   Thanks.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. For example, you can make your joystick singleton and assign that to the player upon spawn. If you have multiple joysticks in the scene, you can group them under the same parent object and make that parent singleton.

Assuming you only have one joystick in the scene, add this into your joystick class:

```
public static MovementJoystick Instance { get; private set; }
void Awake()
{
    if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }
    else
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

In your player class, add this:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    if( movemaneJoystick == null)
    {
        movementJoystick = MovementJoystick.Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please do the same for my buttons? I have edited the original question to show the buttons scripts too.

Comment: @SSam202020 What is your question? If you want your player to get those monobehaviours just use the same pattern in my answer.

Comment: i tried it and it just kept on giving errors that every time i tried to fix it didnt work can you please do it i have even provided the scripts in the main questions

Comment: @SSam202020 Then you have to fix those errors one by one. I have no idea what errors you are having. Posting those errors in a new question could be more helpful.

Comment: I have posted the error in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838293/how-to-fix-error-cs1061-unity-not-what-it-seems-like-very-confusing