# Error cs1061 in Unity, C#, gameobject field resetting on game start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my prefab get's instantiated, the field gets emptied. The following images explain it:

What it currently looks like when instantiated:

[image]

What it is supposed to look like:

[image]

This script (that is currently attached to the button) has solved the problem for other objects but not the button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShootButton : MonoBehaviour
{
public static ShootButton Instance { get; private set; }
void Awake()
{
    if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }
    else
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
}
```

This script is attached to the player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Button shootButton;

void OnEnable()
{
    if (shootButton == null)
    {
        shootButton = ShootButton.Instance;
    }
}

void Start()
{
    shootButton.onClick.AddListener(shootButtonTrue);
}

void shootButtonTrue()
{
    Shoot();
}

void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
}
}
```

I get this error:

```
Assets\stuff\Scripts\Weapon.cs(16,27): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShootButton' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Button'
```

Comment: Well in script two you defined shootbutton as button not your shoot button class.

Comment: i dont know how to fix that

Comment: Dont write "Button ShootButton" as a) that variable name clashes with your class name. B) you want to define ShootButton which was the class you made.

Comment: As i said. Dont declare it as Button. If you struggle with this I would recommend you do some basic c# tutorials

Comment: i changed it to something different but then the input stopped working as a button so i changed it back to Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idk but try

```
public Button shootButton;

void OnEnable()
{
    if (shootButton == null)
    {
        shootButton = ShootButton.Instance.GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}
```

if it is not working try :

```
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public GameObject shoot;



void OnEnable()
{
    if (shootButton == null)
    {
        shoot = ShootButton.Instance;
    }
}
void Start()
{
    shoot.GetComponent<Button>();
    shootButton.onClick.AddListener(shootButtonTrue);
}
```

and again if it s not working :

```
public Button shootButton;
public Button shootButtonPrefab;

void OnEnable()
{
    if (shootButton == null)
    {
        Instantiate(shootButtonPrefab, gameObject.transform);
        shootButton = GameObject.Find("the name of the button prefab").GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already fixed it